# Standard UITableViewCell with dynamic height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to know is it possible to have a standard `UITableViewCell` with style `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` having dynamic height?

**If yes, then how to achieve that?**

- I do not want to customize and make a new class and nib for the cell.
- I have set the `numberOfLines` property of `cell.textLabel` and `cell.detailTextLabel` to `0`.

---

Alright, if your `textLabel` contains multiple line content and `detailTextLabel` contains single line content, then the tableView adjusts cell height automatically. But if it is other way round then it doesn't! Is this a bug by Apple? or expected functionality?

Below are the screen shots

[image]  [image]

Comment: on what basis(basically using which content), you need to create cells with dynamic height?

Comment: din't quiet get you. I need a cell with title and subtitle and UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle gives us that. Now if my title and subtitle are more than 1 line, then how to get dynamic height in that scenario? I know the cell can be subclassed and you can add your own label and constraints. But is there a way to achieve that without subclassing?

Comment: Why don't you want to subclass it?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo Just curious to know if thats possible, else I would be left with no option but to subclass it. Also, I only need to set 2 labels and `UITableViewCell` is providing me that, so if the cell expands based on the content then it would be perfect, without having unnecessary files.

Comment: I have the same problem (uh, even in 2017). For me it works only when I create a custom UITableViewCell class. Strange.

Comment: I also want to use dynamic height with default UITableViewCell without any subclassing, it works in iOS11, but not iOS10. Do you have any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 10;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Title";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"SubTitle text SubTitle text SubTitle text SubTitle text SubTitle text SubTitle text SubTitle text SubTitle text SubTitle text SubTitle text SubTitle text SubTitle text SubTitle text SubTitle text SubTitle text SubTitle text SubTitle text";
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It is Working For me

Answer (score 0):

Your question is well-answered here, for your use-case you are going to have to sub-class UITableViewCell: [Swift Automatic Row Height for Subtitle Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421670/swift-automatic-row-height-for-subtitle-cell)

I believe that a static height for the subtitle is deliberate, as the User Interaction for a subtitle is meant to convey information at-a-glance, rather than the content to which the cell points: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Answer (score -1):

you can get total lines required for that label with given string

```
- (int)lineCountForLabel:(UILabel *)label {
    CGSize size = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font      constrainedToSize:label.frame.size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return ceil(size.height / label.font.lineHeight);
}
```

then just multiply totalNumberOfLines with height for a line and return that count in HeightForRowAtIndexPath.