# Swift Automatic Row Height for Subtitle Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using a subtitle cell in a UITableView. I have set the following in `viewDidLoad` to make the row height automatically expand:

```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

I have also set the title and subtitle of the cell to word wrap:

```
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

    cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.detailTextLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

When I type in the title, all is good. But the subtitle does not expand the row. Is there something else I need to do to get the subtitle to increase the row height?

[image]

Comment: If you are using the standard "subtitle" style of table view cell, you will have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587126/autolayout-ignores-multi-line-detailtextlabel-when-calculating-uitableviewcell-h You can override the `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:` function or set a custom style cell with constrains (and connected labels instead of textLabel and detailTextLabel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using this code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40168001/4045472 and define the cell as:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {

        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        var size = super.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: horizontalFittingPriority, verticalFittingPriority: verticalFittingPriority)

        if let textLabel = self.textLabel, let detailTextLabel = self.detailTextLabel {
            let detailHeight = detailTextLabel.frame.size.height
            if detailTextLabel.frame.origin.x > textLabel.frame.origin.x { // style = Value1 or Value2
                let textHeight = textLabel.frame.size.height
                if (detailHeight > textHeight) {
                    size.height += detailHeight - textHeight
                }
            } else { // style = Subtitle, so always add subtitle height
                size.height += detailHeight
            }
        }

        return size

    }

}
```

And change the cell custom class in storyboard to MyTableViewCell will set the correct size automatically.

In the table view datasource's tableView:cellForRow: function, after set the labels' text, call `cell.setNeedsLayout()` to force it adjust layout.

Comment: The other answers only handle the main title changing which was working, but this indeed increases the row height when the subtitle changes as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You should take one lable and give constrain like that,
[image]

After that, write this two delegate method of tableview.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

So, tableview height increse as per lable text size.

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to set constraints so that the cell can size automatically based on the size of the label. Here is a tutorial on dynamic cells. https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells